# AMA Agent Installation via Azure Arc & Data Collection Rule in Microsoft Sentinel

Tags: azure, azure-sentinel, azure-arc

I cannot install the AMA Agent on client's computer, which does not have any permissions.

I am trying to install AMA Agent on Client's computer using Azure Arc & Data Collection Rule. They don't have any permission. My current rule is "Contributor" rule. I downloaded the script file and sent it to them. But the problem is when the run the script I downloaded there is an error that shows. "FATAL resource failed with status code 403"
[image]

Answer (score 0):

> I cannot install the AMA Agent on client's computer, which does not have any permissions.

The error `FATAL resource failed with status code 403` appears to be connected to a permissions problem.

I encounter the following problem while attempting to install the `Azure Monitor Agent` with a `non-administrator` account.

[image]

To resolve the issue, open `Powershell` with administrative rights install the `Azure Monitor Agent` on it. The `Contributor` role in Azure focuses primarily on managing Azure resources and does not give the client machine administrative access.

[image]

Comment: Thanks for your reply,
I have tried "Run as Administrator". When we run the script on the client computer, authentication with the account which has the "Contributor" role is required. But the client must not have that kind of role. That's my problem.

Comment: If you are trying to authenticate, its required role to access particular resource in Azure but installing any application on client computer Admin privileges is enough. if possible, kindly share your PowerShell code (ONboardingscript.Ps1)